# Did H. G. Wells use artificial intelligence in any story?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, h.g.wells

My sense is that he did not. In fact the closest he comes is in [The Island of Doctor Moreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_of_Doctor_Moreau).

The Martian machines needed pilots.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no

Comment: I think biology and fast travel, inspired by trains and flight and advances in public health and genetics, interested  Wells and Verne. But there were stirrings of AI -- the Mechanical Turk interested people also it was a known fake. But there was a chess machine that with just relays to mate with a k + r vs k, perhaps the biggest thing in artificial intelligence until the 1940s.

Comment: May be of interest https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_computers and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_robots_and_androids

Comment: Of course the bots of RUR were of flesh and blood, closer to Moreau than Metropolis.

Comment: I was thinking about the Time Machine movie with Guy Pearce, and there is a hologram played by Orlando Jones. Was the hologram taken from the book, or was that a movie only addition?

Comment: @DafyddNZ: heck of a thing if the hologram was in the book but it was not.

Comment: @releseabe Thanks, I've never read the book so I didn't know.